# Using Laravel without ORM?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I'm starting my first project in Laravel and learning it from scratch. This project will tie in to existing mysql tables (with millions of records in dozens of tables). I'm anxious to get the site online quickly and get Googlebot spidering it, while I work on the non-crawlable pages and layout. It will likely take Googlebot several months to spider all the content, and probably a month before they start adding my site to their index and the first hits start showing up in the search results. By that time, the content won't have changed much, but the appearance will have. Never having used a framework before, let alone controllers/models/views etc, I have a steep learning curve to add enough Eloquent to be functional. And my timetable is short.

Is there any reason that I can't just use plain ole' php for the data retrieval for now, and then replace it with eloquent code in a month or two when I've "mastered" the rest of Laravel enough to come back to it? There will only be a handful of queries at first. I'll have to carefully test the Eloquent to avoid disrupting the live data. So it will take time to plan a testing strategy and create test versions of the tables, etc.

Anything that would bite me in the butt if I tried this?

Comment: You can, although you'd be shocked at how easy Eloquent is. At least consider using the [database class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database) even without Eloquent - stuff like `$users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);` is stupidly easy. :-D

Comment: I'm with @ceejayoz here. Learning Eloquent, while not instantaneous, is a lot easier than trying to learn how to glom on some legacy PHP code that handles your database access. Plus you won't have to un-do everything you hack in and do it properly later. It doesn't take long, and it uses a number of very safe defaults you might not otherwise consider using. Work through the examples, ask for help when you need it. There's an enthusiastic community there to back you up.

Comment: google is clueless how you feed your pages. It could be thru to soup cans attached by string. And while you get stuck in the ORM, you will come to us raw query writers anyway :p

Comment: Successfully tested ceejayoz's suggestion, works great! Back on schedule...